# Cannot get the demo code for unslider to work

Tags: jquery

I am trying to follow the instructions on http://unslider.com/ but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have, nothing displays.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
        .banner li { list-style: none; }
            .banner ul li { float: left; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <li>This is a slide.</li>
            <li>This is another slide.</li>
            <li>This is a final slide.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script>
            $(function() {
                $('.banner').unslider();
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your javascript console. Anything in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see some images , add some images

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .banner li { list-style: none; }
        .banner ul li { float: left; }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wpcontent/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="http://s3.firstpost.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/300vsSA-Getty.jpg"></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reason http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wpcontent/uploads/2012/10/06_Place_20773_1_Mis.jpg didn't load on my end, so as an Australian I added a jpeg of Shane Warne as image #1 :) , works great. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't have any `css` added in your code, where original side has following css added

```
http://unslider.com/style.css
```

[Check this working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8vm/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this nice tutorial!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBOB9scHnwo

1. You need to include the scripts

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. the styles for the banner div

   ```
   <style>
       .banner {
           position: relative;
           width: 100%;
           overflow: auto;
           padding: 0px;
           margin: 0px;
       }
       .banner ul {
           padding: 0px;
           margin: 0px;
       }
       .banner li{
       padding: 0px;
       margin: 0px;
       }
       .banner ul li {
           float:left;
           padding: 0px;
           margin: 0px;
           min-height: 200px;
           -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
           -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
           -o-background-size: 100% auto;
           -ms-background-size: 100% auto;
           background-size: 100% auto;
           background-position-y: -75px;
           box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       }
   </style>
   ```
3. and start unslider

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.banner').unslider({
           speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
           delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
           complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
           keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
           dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
           fluid: true              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
           });
        });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you miss the CSS styles. Put this in your `<head>`:

```
<style>
    @import url("http://unslider.com/style.css");
    .banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .banner li { list-style: none; }
    .banner ul li { float: left; }
</style>
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/AmUXimE/2/edit)